# Set-ADuser in Foreach

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I tried to set the value Company into the ad field Company and it should Filter by Homepage (this works). And I get this error:

cmdlet Set-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity:

```
$users = $null

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Homepage -like "www.test.ch"' -Searchbase “OU=TestOu, OU=test Lyss, DC=ads,DC=test,DC=CH"  



ForEach($user in $users)
{
    
    Set-ADUser -Identity -Company 'Company' 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, in your `foreach` loop, you're calling the `-Identity` parameter but never giving any value to the argument, like `-Identity $user`. In addition, it can be piped directly:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Homepage -like 'www.test.ch'" -Searchbase 'OU=TestOu,OU=test Lyss,DC=ads,DC=test,DC=CH' |
Set-ADUser -Company 'Company'
```

Comment: is -Identity the $user from Get-ADUser or the guid for the object?  The documentation is not clear what Identity should be passed

Comment: @GoldenLion `-Identity` refers to: "You can identify a user by its distinguished name, GUID, security identifier (SID), or Security Account Manager (SAM) account name.". It can take those 4 values

Comment: I just realized that SID was a good choice.    how do I tell set-aduser to only search a certain part of the OU and device controller path when updating.  It look like in the error message of insufficient rights it was at the root